# catch keydown events in inner components using react-keydown

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

I'm using react-keydown library for adding keyboard shortcuts to my application, but can't make it work in inner dialogs components. The dialogs are not always visible, but I expect the keys to work when they are visible.
I'm getting to *event_handlers.js._onKeyDown(event)* method, but with missing value: *fn = undefined*, whereas *fn* should contain the decorated function.

My components looks like:

```
<Container>
   <MyDialog>
      <material-ui-dialog/>
   </MyDialog>
</Container>
```

Container.js:

```
import keydown from 'react-keydown'
class Container extends Component {
   @keydown('enter') 
   someMethod1(){
      // working
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <MyDialog/>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

MyDialog.js:

```
import keydown, {keydownScoped} from 'react-keydown'
@keydown('enter')
class MyDialog extends Component {
   @keydownScoped('enter')
   someMethod3(){
      // not working
   } 
}
```

Comment: What is the logic that determines whether it is visible or not? Also, can you confirm that you're not trying to trigger the key-bound method when focused on a form field?

Comment: The dialog is not always visible. It is a confirmation dialog (which contains material ui dialog) that is triggered by some other action in the component. There is no input field or text area in the component, only a dialog with ok/cancel buttons.

Comment: Is it mounted even when it's not visible? The issue could be that if it's already mounted, but hidden, and you click or tab to a component outside the scope of the dialog component it's keybindings won't respond.

Comment: Yes, all my dialogs are mounted when the application start. How can I handle key events for each one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description in the comments, the issue appears to be that your Dialog components mount and then lose focus so any keybindings inside them will not receive the keystrokes. You have a couple of options:

1) Expand the scope of the keybinding by decorating a component that is an ancestor of your Dialog components and won't lose focus. In an extreme case this could be the root component of your app. Then decorate the desired Dialog component method with `keydownScoped`. Inside that method examine the props to make sure the current dialog is the active one.

2) Programmatically activate your Dialog keybindings along the lines of this https://github.com/glortho/react-keydown/issues/28.

Hope that helps!